# Select from Openquery to Oracle, missing quotation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to successfully run a code with openquery to a oracle server.

Please do not take into account field names/data types, as I had to present only a part of the whole procedure. It's quite long.
I believe the problem lies in quotation marks, etc...

The procedure compiles all right.
Each time I execute the procedure, an error occurs:

Quote:
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'SELECT TO_NUMBER(XYZ_1) XYZ_1,
XYZ_2,

cast (''''0'''' as number(5)) as B1, 
cast(''''1753-01-01'''' as date) NULL_DATE

I am lost - where the heck should I put those missing quotation mark?

Code:

Code: [Select all] [Show/ hide]
CREATE TABLE #tmpXYZ Header (
    [XYZ_1] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [XYZ_2] varchar,
    [XYZ_3] varchar,
        -- more fields
    [XYZ_N] varchar
 )

declare @sqlInv nvarchar(3000)
 set @sqlInv =

```
    'insert into #tmpXYZ Header (
    [XYZ_1],
    [XYZ_2],
    [XYZ_3],
    -- more fields
    [XYZ_N]

)

select
    * FROM OPENQUERY(XYZ_ORACLE, 
    ''SELECT TO_NUMBER(XYZ_1) XYZ_1,
    XYZ_2,

    cast (''''0'''' as number(5)) as B1, 
    cast(''''1753-01-01'''' as date) NULL_DATE,
    -- more fields
    cast ('''' '''' as varchar(20)) as A19 

from XYZ.V_HEADER 
where

    (DATE >= ''''TO_DATE(''''' + @startDate + ''''', ''''YYYYMMDD'''')'''' AND 
    DATE <= ''''TO_DATE(''''' + @endDate + ''''', ''''YYYYMMDD'''')'''' AND 
    QWE = ''''0'''' AND
    ABC = ''''13'''' ) '' )
' 

exec sp_executesql @sqlInv
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong you are passing a string.
So you start the insert with a quote.

Afterwards you do a double quote for select to_number(XYZ_1) XYZ_1, ......
I think this is right because you are passing again a string to openquery command.

But why are you putting 4 quotes in between the cast statements. You just have to put in 2 quotes to escape the quote. I think there is your mistake unless I'm getting this wrong.